# Pyqt5 QMDIarea subclass with a custom signal on close

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I need to create a custom signal on `Qmdisubwindow` close. In other word, when I closed any subwindow, a signal is emitted with the name of that window being closed. Below is my trail, but seems not right. Error occurs as:

1. a subwindow already created without calling
2. add subwindow option is not working
3. closable action is not working

Hope you can show me how to fix it.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MyMdi(QMdiSubWindow):

   sigClosed = pyqtSignal(str)

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
      super(MyMdi, self).__init__(parent)
      

   def closeEvent(self, event):
      """Get the name of active window about to close
      """
      name = name
      self.sigClosed.emit('{} is close'.format(name))
      QMdiSubWindow.closeEvent(self, event)



class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   count = 0
    
   def __init__(self, parent = None):
      super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
      
      self.mdi = MyMdi()
      self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
      bar = self.menuBar()
        
      file = bar.addMenu("File")
      file.addAction("New")
      file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.windowaction)
      self.setWindowTitle("MDI demo")

      # my signal
      self.mdi.sigClosed.connect(self.windowclosed)

   @pyqtSlot(str)
   def windowclosed(self, text):
      print(text)

        
   def windowaction(self, q):
        
      if q.text() == "New":
         MainWindow.count = MainWindow.count+1
         sub = QMdiSubWindow()
         sub.setWidget(QTextEdit())
         sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow"+str(MainWindow.count))
         self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
         sub.show()
        
def main():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = MainWindow()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an initial error: a QMdiSubWindow must be inside a QMdiArea but there is none in your code.

On the other hand, the idea of subclassing is good but you have several drawbacks:

- You are not using it initially since there is no QMdiArea, if you execute the QAction then your application will be closed because a QMdiSubWindow does not have any method called addSubWindow.
- The QMdiSubWindow does not have an attribute called name, you must use windowTitle.

```
class MdiSubWindow(QMdiSubWindow):
    sigClosed = pyqtSignal(str)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """Get the name of active window about to close
      """
        self.sigClosed.emit(self.windowTitle())
        QMdiSubWindow.closeEvent(self, event)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    count = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.mdi = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi)
        bar = self.menuBar()

        file = bar.addMenu("File")
        file.addAction("New")
        file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.windowaction)
        self.setWindowTitle("MDI demo")

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def windowclosed(self, text):
        print(text)

    def windowaction(self, q):
        if q.text() == "New":
            MainWindow.count = MainWindow.count + 1
            sub = MdiSubWindow()
            sub.setWidget(QTextEdit())
            sub.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            sub.setWindowTitle("subwindow" + str(MainWindow.count))
            sub.sigClosed.connect(self.windowclosed)
            self.mdi.addSubWindow(sub)
            sub.show()
```

Comment: Working just fine, Thanks. One inquiry, when you call 'sub.close()'; does this delete the subwindow and its widget? Or I have to call deleteLater()?

Comment: by default no, so I added `sub.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)` which calls deleteLater() when the window is closed.